# Is this a valid way to send document downloadURL to Firebase Firestore database? (React/NextJS)

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a form that collects user data (name, mobile, email...) and the form also has an input which accepts multiple documents. All data is being stored with useReducer and useContext on change (as soon as the user inputs a value).
The idea was to wait for a form submit and then:

1. upload files to Firebase Storage
2. retrieve URLs for each file
3. push these URLs to the state (using a reducer method)
4. send the user data to Firestore database

My issue is that the userData object is being sent to the database with an empty document URLs array. It appears that the addDoc function isn't waiting for the promises to fulfill.

So I cloned the userData object, pushed the received URLs to dokumentiURLs within the clone, and add the cloned object to addDoc function. This appears to be working as intended.

Is this a valid way of doing this or can my code be somehow changed to work without cloning the state object?

Here is the code:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      //later added - cloning the state object
      let userDataToSend = { ...userData };
      const uploadedUrls = await Promise.all(
        dokumenti.map(async (file) => {
          const storageRef = ref(storage, `2324/${userData.oib}/${file.name}`);
          const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            uploadTask.on(
              "state_changed",
              (snapshot) => {
                const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                setProgress(progress);
              },
              (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                reject(error);
              },
              () => {
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
                  .then((downloadURL) => {
                    resolve(downloadURL);
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                  });
              }
            );
          });
        })
      );
      setDocumentLinks([...userData.dokumentiURLs, ...uploadedUrls]);

      //later added - update the cloned object with recieved URLs
      userDataToSend.dokumentiURLs = [...uploadedUrls];

      await addDoc(applicationCollection, userDataToSend);
      getApplications();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```